# Need conversion from MASM to NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

Attached Files:
File dosbox_003.png (5.722 KB)
Write a NASM which will:

Display your name on one line.  (Use int 21h, function 9.  The characters for carriage return and linefeed are 0Dh and 0Ah, respectively.)
On the next line, display a prompt (once again using int 21h, function9) and read three characters from the keyboard (using int 21h, fcn 1.)  Store the characters in appropriately labeled byte variables.
Print the three characters, one per line, (Depending on how you implement this, use either int 21h, function 9, or function 2, your choice.)
Assemble your program using NASM and execute it using DOSBox.

assembling with command prompt

given this code (with errors bolded and lines highlighted)
i have these errors

```
C:\NASM>nasm bal-lab2.asm -o bal-lab2.com
bal-lab2.asm:5: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local 
labels
bal-lab2.asm:5: error: parser: instruction expected
bal-lab2.asm:6: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local 
labels
bal-lab2.asm:6: error: parser: instruction expected
bal-lab2.asm:7: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in 
error [-w+orphan-labels]
bal-lab2.asm:7: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local 
labels
bal-lab2.asm:17: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in 
error [-w+orphan-labels]
bal-lab2.asm:18: error: parser: instruction expected
bal-lab2.asm:127: error: symbol `main' redefined
bal-lab2.asm:127: error: parser: instruction expected
bal-lab2.asm:128: error: parser: instruction expected
```

with this code

```
;ff
;ff
;ff

.model small line ***LINE 5***
.stack 100h ***LINE 6***
.data ***LINE 7***  
nameString db 'my name here $' ;replace by your name
prompt1 db 'Enter first character : $' ;ask for character
prompt2 db 'Enter second character : $' ;ask for character
prompt3 db 'Enter third character : $' ;ask for character

character1 DB ? ;memory to store character
character2 DB ? ;memory to store character
character3 DB ? ;memory to store character

.code ***LINE 17**
main proc ***LINE 18***


mov ax,@data ;move data address to ax
mov ds,ax ;move ax to data segment  


lea dx , nameString ;move content to dx

mov ah,9 ;ask to print array of string
int 21h

mov dx,10 ;print \n
mov ah,2
int 21h  

mov dx,13 ;cursor at first position
mov ah,2
int 21h

lea dx , prompt1 ;if use lea no need to use offset

mov ah,9 ;print prompt
int 21h  
;ask for character input
mov ah,1
int 21h

mov character1,al ; move to labled memory


mov dx,10 ;print \n
mov ah,2
int 21h  

mov dx,13 ;cursor at first position
mov ah,2
int 21h

lea dx , prompt2 ;if use lea no need to use offset

mov ah,9 ;print prompt
int 21h  
;ask for character input
mov ah,1
int 21h

mov character2,al ; move to labled memory


mov dx,10 ;print \n
mov ah,2
int 21h  

mov dx,13 ;cursor at first position
mov ah,2
int 21h

lea dx , prompt3 ;if use lea no need to use offset

mov ah,9 ;print prompt
int 21h  
;ask for character input
mov ah,1
int 21h

mov character3,al ; move to labled memory  


mov dx,10 ;print \n
mov ah,2
int 21h  

mov dx,13 ;cursor at first position
mov ah,2
int 21h

mov dl,character1 ;move character value to dl for print
mov ah,2
int 21h

mov dx,10 ;print \n
mov ah,2
int 21h  

mov dx,13 ;cursor at first position
mov ah,2
int 21h

mov dl,character2 ;move character value to dl for print
mov ah,2
int 21h


mov dx,10 ;print \n
mov ah,2
int 21h  

mov dx,13 ;cursor at first position
mov ah,2
int 21h

mov dl,character3 ;move character value to dl for print
mov ah,2
int 21h


mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp ***LINE 127***
end main ***LINE 128***
```

the errors are highlighted and the lines too
id appreciate any help, im very new to assembly language

Comment: Your code appears to be in MASM syntax (not NASM). NASM can't process MASM syntax. You'll need to use MASM (or something compatible like TASM or even JWASM) to assemble this file. Otherwise yuou'd have to convert this to NASM syntax.

Answer (score 2):

- Remove first 7 lines of program and replace with `org 0x100`
- Move everything in `.data` to end of file. Section not required in COM files.
- Change all occurences of `db ?` to `db 0`
- Remove lines 17 to 22 **mov ax,@data** and **mov ds,ax** not required
- Every place you've used `lea` change to `mov`
- Change all instances of `character?` to `[character?]`

Make those changes and your program will work, I tested it using DOSBox 0.74 with output that looks like this;

> ```
> my name here
> Enter first character : R
> Enter second character : a
> Enter third character : m
> R
> a
> m
> ```

This is your program in modified for NASM and with a few personal tweaks such as shortened labels

```
        org 256

        mov     dx, Nme         ;move content to dx

        mov     ah, 9       ;ask to print array of string
        int     21h

        mov     dx, 10      ;print \n
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h  

        mov     dx, 13      ;cursor at first position
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h

        mov     dx, prompt1     ;if use lea no need to use offset
        mov     ah, 9       ;print prompt
        int     21h  

        mov     ah, 1       ;ask for chr input
        int     21h
        mov     [chr1] ,al  ; move to labled memory

        mov     dx, 10      ;print \n
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h  

        mov     dx, 13      ;cursor at first position
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h

        mov     dx , prompt2    ;if use lea no need to use offset

        mov     ah, 9       ;print prompt
        int     21h  

        mov     ah,1        ;ask for chr input
        int     21h
        mov     [chr2], al  ; move to labled memory

        mov     dx, 10      ;print \n
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h  

        mov     dx, 13      ;cursor at first position
        mov     ah,2
        int     21h

        mov     dx, prompt3     ;if use lea no need to use offset
        mov     ah, 9       ;print prompt
        int     21h

        mov     ah, 1
        int 21h
        mov     [chr3], al   ; move to labled memory 

        mov     dx, 10      ;print \n
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h  

        mov     dx, 13      ;cursor at first position
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h

        mov dl, [chr1]      ;move chr value to dl for print
        mov     ah, 2
        int 21h

        mov     dx, 10      ;print \n
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h  

        mov     dx, 13      ;cursor at first position
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h

        mov     dl, [chr2]  ;move chr value to dl for print
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h

        mov     dx, 10      ;print \n
        mov ah, 2
        int     21h  

        mov     dx, 13      ;cursor at first position
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h

        mov     dl, [chr3]  ;move chr value to dl for print
        mov     ah, 2
        int     21h

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h

        Nme:        db  'my name here $' ;replace by your name
        prompt1:    db  'Enter  first chr: $' ;ask for chr
        prompt2:    db  'Enter second chr: $' ;ask for chr
        prompt3:    db  'Enter  third chr: $' ;ask for chr

        chr1:   DB 0    ;memory to store chr
        chr2:   DB 0    ;memory to store chr
        chr3:   DB 0    ;memory to store chr
```

Comment: what is meant by change all instances of character? to [character?] ive got to the point where                                                                  
my only errors are invalid combination of opcode and operands on the mov character1-3,al lines

Comment: Substitute the question marks for 1, 2 or 3. So where you have `character3` that needs to be changed to `[character3]`. Unlike MASM, when you want the contents of a memory location, it needs to be enclosed in brackets.

Comment: when changed to [character?], i recieve error: unrecognised directive

Comment: sorry, i should have clarified, the ? is replaced by 1-3, and the errors im getting are with https://gyazo.com/3955d24b75863756cd3f56bef5925502 when not having the [], and i get the unrecognized directive when i use this https://gyazo.com/7cdca36b643a943c66860c23a817c0fc

Comment: @ArthurL declarations still remain as `character1 db 0`, but when you want to move the contents into DL then it would be `mov dl,[character1]` or `mov [character1],dl` to save DL at that memory location.